# RCurl memory leak in getURL method

Tags: r, memory-leaks, rcurl

It looks like we have hit a bug in RCurl. The method getURL seems to be leaking memory. A simple test case to reproduce the bug is given here:

```
library(RCurl)
handle<-getCurlHandle()
range<-1:100
for (r in range) {x<-getURL(url="news.google.com.au",curl=handle)}
```

If I run this code, the memory allocated to the R session is never recovered.

We are using RCurl for some long running experiments and we are running out of memory on the test system.

The specs of our test system are as follows:

OS: Ubuntu  14.04 (64 bit)

Memory: 24 GB

RCurl version: 1.95-4.3

Any ideas about how to get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Grab the [source](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.3.tar.gz) grab the [latest curl library](http://curl.haxx.se/), test it with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and submit a patch (being serious, this is community developed software)

Comment: We've discovered some minor leaks in RCurl in the past. We will contact and work with Duncan to resolve these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if `getURLContent()` also exhibits the problem, i.e. replace `getURL()` with `getURLContent()`.
The function `getURLContent()` is a richer version of `getURL()` and one that gets more attention.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I will try getURLContent and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: running a test using getURLContent shows no increase in memory. Will incorporate it in the actual application on Monday and mark your post as the answer if everything works fine. Thanks Duncan.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this too, and made the following code change to work around it:

LEAK (Old code)

```
h = basicHeaderGatherer()
tmp = tryCatch(getURL(url = url,
                      headerfunction = h$update,
                      useragent = R.version.string,
                      timeout = timeout_secs),
               error = function(x) { .__curlError <<- TRUE; __curlErrorMessage <<- x$message })
```

NO LEAK (New code)

```
method <- "GET"
h <- basicHeaderGatherer()
t <- basicTextGatherer()
tmp <- tryCatch(curlPerform(url = url,
                            customrequest = method,
                            writefunction = t$update,
                            headerfunction = h$update,
                            useragent=R.version.string,
                            verbose = FALSE,
                            timeout = timeout_secs),
                error = function(x) { .__curlError <<- TRUE; .__curlErrorMessage <<- x$message })
```